# Python and Numba for vectorized functions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

Good day, I'm writing a Python module for some numeric work. Since there's a lot of stuff going on, I've been spending the last few days optimizing code to improve calculations times.
However, I have a question concerning Numba.
Basically, I have a class with some fields which are numpy arrays, which I initialize in the following way:

```
def init(self):
    a = numpy.arange(0, self.max_i, 1)
    self.vibr_energy = self.calculate_vibr_energy(a)

def calculate_vibr_energy(i):
    return numpy.exp(-self.harmonic * i - self.anharmonic * (i ** 2))
```

So, the code is vectorized, and using Numba's JIT results in some improvement. However, sometimes I need to access the calculate_vibr_energy function from outside the class, and pass a single integer instead of an array in place of i.
As far as I understand, if I use Numba's JIT on the calculate_vibr_energy, it will have to always take an array as an argument.

So, which of the following options is better:
1) Create a new function calculate_vibr_energy_single(i), which will only take a single integer number, and use Numba on it too
2) Replace all usages of the function that are similar to this one:

```
myclass.calculate_vibr_energy(1)
```

with this:

```
tmp = np.array([1])
myclass.calculate_vibr_energy(tmp)[0]
```

Or are there other, more efficient (or at least, more Python-ic) ways of doing that?

Comment: He meant numba. numba is a JIT compiler for numpy: https://github.com/numba/numba

Comment: A third option could be to pass an array of length 1 instead of an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only played a little with numba yet so I may be mistaken, but as far as I've understood it, using the "autojit" decorator should give functions that can take arguments of any type.

See e.g. http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/pythonstuff.html

Comment: Thanks! This seems the most simple way (and readability-friendly) way to do it.